How can I add a keyboard toolbar button to show the Format sheet in SwiftUI?
How can I add a keyboard toolbar button, which shows the Format sheet by one click. Apple Notes has this functionality in their app like this.
I have tried this.
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
struct SimpleTextView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ViewController {
        let viewController = ViewController()
        viewController.text = text
        return viewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ViewController, context: Context) {
        uiViewController.updateTextView(text: text)
    }
}


import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var text: String = "Implementing a Rich Text Editor has become a nightmare for iOS developers so far. Finally Apple announced an exciting update to UITextView for rich text editing."
    var formatSheetVisible: Bool = false

    lazy var textView: UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 500))
        textView.center = view.center
        textView.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 21)
        textView.borderStyle = .none
        textView.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
        
        return textView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(textView)
        textView.text = text
    }
    
    func updateTextView(text: String) {
        textView.text = text
    }
}

#Preview {
    ViewController()
}

But I have to tap format and then tap more... and then the Format sheet will present.

.toolbar does this without all the UIKit code

Use can customise using .toolbar as per your requirement.
Like this:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var name = "Taylor"

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Enter your name", text: $name)
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                    Button("Click me!") {
                        print("Clicked")
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}


Reference: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-a-toolbar-to-the-keyboard

Did you try this solution?
